# How could I eliminate the errors I am getting?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfyzk.png)
[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hQPD.png)

In PL/SQL, I was attempting to create a function named "get_term_gpa" returns the term GPA for a student given the student’s pid and yrtrm as parameters with a GROUP BY function to get the SUM() of the gpa given the pid and yrtrm, and then divide the SUM() by the count(*) for classes taken during that semester to derive that GPA.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code; copy and paste the code as text.

Comment: You are only `SELECT`ing one expression and have two variables in the `INTO` clause. Replace `/` with `,` and you will select two things. (You may also want to use `AVG` rather than `SUM`.)

Comment: There are several things wrong with your code. MT0's comments are both correct. Also the GROUP BY isn't needed. You don't need to initialize v_gpa to 0. You don't use v_total. You reuse v_gpa giving it two meanings. That is bad coding practice. Checking for v_total_rows > 0 makes sense because sum(grade_points) will be null if no rows match your where clause. You don't show the definition of ENROLLMENTS. Does it have the SEMESTER column?

Comment: @BobbyDurrett `v_total_rows > 0` does not actually make sense in the OP's code as they use a `GROUP BY` clause and if 0 rows are matched then the query will throw a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception (rather than returning a count of 0 rows). [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F1GBau_7)

Comment: @MT0 You are right. My assumption was that the OP would remove the redundant GROUP BY. Without the redundant GROUP BY the count() would always return a number. It is a good way to check if a query returns anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you `SELECT` one expression `SUM(grade_points)/COUNT(*)` but you are trying to put that one thing `INTO` two variables. You would want to change it to:

```sql
SELECT SUM(grade_points), COUNT(*) INTO v_gpa, v_total_rows
```

However, lots of the function is unnecessary (such as `v_total`, the `GROUP BY` clause and `v_total_rows` is also unnecessary if you use `AVG` and not `SUM`) and you can simplify it all to:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_term_gpa(
  pid   IN ENROLLMENTS.STUDENT_ID%TYPE,
  yrtrm IN ENROLLMENTS.SEMESTER%TYPE
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_gpa ENROLLMENTS.GRADE_POINTS%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT COALESCE(AVG(grade_points), 0)
  INTO   v_gpa
  FROM   enrollments
  WHERE  student_id = pid
  AND    semester   = yrtrm;

  RETURN v_gpa;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you, but your simplified code has returned the following errors:

Error at line 1/17: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_230100", line 797
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_230100", line 782
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2035

Comment: @GatteringRam Then use `CREATE OR REPLACE ...` or drop the existing function first and then `CREATE` the updated version.

Comment: That has returned these errors:
Error at line 0: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
Error at line 2: PLS-00201: identifier 'ENROLLMENTS.STUDENT_ID' must be declared

Comment: @GatteringRam I am using the exact same table and column names that **YOU** specified in your question; please debug your own code and make sure that the table and column identifiers **YOU** declare in the table exactly match the identifiers used in the function. We do not have your tables so this is something **YOU** are going to have to fix.